# How do you select the next tab

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs

So, there are plenty of solutions to select the next tab like so

```
var selected = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected");
$("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", selected + 1);
```

however, if my next tab is disabled, and I want it to go 2 tabs over instead, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm answering my own question here, not too complicated, though I thought I'd share what I came up with ( written in coffeescript )

```
current = @$el.tabs('option', 'selected')
counter = 1
while current == @$el.tabs('option', 'selected') and current + counter <= @$el.tabs('length')
  @$el.tabs 'select', current + counter++
```

I also thought about perhaps sending a keyboard event to the tabs to simulate a right arrow key.  Comments welcome